# PHP/MySQL - Cannot get PHP script to put data into MySQL Database

Tags: php, html, mysql, apache, mysqli

I've spent most of the day trying to get data from a form into a MySQL Database, everything I have tried so far has not worked, can anyone figure out what is wrong? The database is connecting fine, it just cannot add any data into the mysql database (current errors are at the bottom)

EDIT: Updated Code Below (Still not working!)

```
<?php
$host = "localhost"; // Host name
$username = "root"; // Mysql username
$password = ""; // Mysql password
$db_name = "report"; // Database name
$tbl_name = "tbl_nonconformance"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select database.

mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die("cannot select DB");
echo "Database Connected    ";

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$supplier = $_POST['supplier'];
$PONum = $_POST['PONum'];
$Part = $_POST['Part'];
$Serial = $_POST['Serial'];
$tsf = $_POST['tsf'];
$Quantity = $_POST['Quantity'];
$probclass = $_POST['probclass'];
$desc = $_POST['desc'];

$sql="INSERT INTO tbl_nonconformance (sno, Date, Name, Email, Supplier, PONum, Part, Serial, TSF, Quantity, probclass, desc)
VALUES
('$sno', '$date', '$name', '$email', '$supplier', '$PONum', '$Part', '$Serial', '$TSF', '$Quantity', '$probclass', '$desc')";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

// if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful".
if($result){
header('Location: ../thankyou.php');
}
else {
echo "ERROR";
}

// close mysql
mysql_close();

?>
```

Comment: So look at the arguments you should be passing to [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) then drop last decades deprecated interface and switch to MySQLi or PDO, and learn to use prepared statements with bind variables

Comment: I think the warnings are clear, e.g. `Undefined variable: con`.

Comment: Are you using `mysqli` or the terribly out of date `mysql_query`? You really should be using `mysqli` exclusively.

Comment: use backticks (`) around all the column names in the 'insert' statement to avoid  any confusion with reserved words.

Answer (score 3):

First you should change

```
 mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die("cannot connect");
```

to:

```
 $con = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die("cannot connect");
```

You are calling `$con` but you never defined it. You want to save your MySQL connection (con) as `$con` for what you are trying to do here.

You should also really consider upgrading to MySQLi as MySQL is deprecated from PHP and will likely be removed from future versions. Here's a resource to get you started. http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

**Edit July 9 2014**: You updated your code, and I do not recall what your original code was. Still, if it's not "working", it's best to describe **how** it's not working. After you call `$result`, do this:

```
if( !$result || !mysql_affected_rows() ) 
   die( mysql_error() );
header('Location: ../thankyou.php'); //this will only occur if there are no SQL errors and the result actually inserted something
mysql_close(); 
echo "We couldn't forward you automatically. Click here to proceed {insert HTML/JS here}";
```

This will return the MySQL error message which will help you in your debugging.

Comment: You should remove the `"` marks around the variables.  They are unnecessary and have a performance impact (admittedly marginal in this case, but in a large project it could add up).

Comment: @timclutton - Good suggestion. I hadn't noticed them earlier when I copied. Edited to adjust.

Comment: I Was originally using MySQLi but it would not function correctly and gave me even more errors than I'm having now, I'll give this a go now

Comment: Just tried your suggestion but had no luck, I've updated the main post with the new code

Answer (score 0):

You got your argument parsing wrong.

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']);
```

`$con` is not defined first of all.

Secondly you are trying to escape `$_POST['name']`.

`mysql_real_escape_string` expects 2 arguments, 1st one is mandatory and second one is optional. First argument is the string you want to escape, the second specifies a mysql connection (optional as you may have one open already).

So your statement needs to look like

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
```

Perhaps `$con` is your mysql connection? Which if it is the case you may want to

`$con = mysql_connect` ........ and so on

Answer (score 0):

you're using un-secure depreciating methods too. You should research PDO object. It separates variables from your query so they aren't sent at the same time. It also cleans code considerably. I see a few problem areas in his code... You pass in $sno, $date, but they don't exist in your code. $tsf has a different case in instantiation then what you're using in your query. You're using single quotes which can't interpolate data (place values where variable names are). Double quotes do that...

hmmm...

check this out.

```
<?php

$host = "localhost"; // Host name
$username = "root"; // Mysql username
$password = ""; // Mysql password
$db_port = "3306" // Mysql port
$db_name = "report"; // Database name
$dsn = "mysql:dbhost=$host;dbport=$db_port;dbname=$db_name";

//add sno variable declaration here.

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$supplier = $_POST['supplier'];
$PONum = $_POST['PONum'];
$Part = $_POST['Part'];
$Serial = $_POST['Serial'];
$TSF = $_POST['tsf']; 
$Quantity = $_POST['Quantity'];
$probclass = $_POST['probclass'];
$desc = $_POST['desc'];
$date = date('d-m-Y');

// Connect to server and select database.

$dbConnect = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

$sqlStatement = $dbConnect->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_nonconformance (sno, Date, Name, Email, Supplier, PONum, Part, Serial, TSF, Quantity, probclass, desc)VALUES('?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?')");

try{

 $sqlStatement->execute(array($sno, $date, $name, $email, $supplier, $PONum, $Part, $Serial, $TSF, $Quantity, $probclass, $desc));

 header('Location: ../thankyou.php');

}catch(\PDOException $e){ 

echo 'Error: Could not connect to db.';

}

?>
```

PDO object is really easy. create $dbConnect = new PDO(). You see the arguments there. dsn, username, password. The last argument is just an associative array setting PDO's error mode with constants. This allows us to use the try catch block to do error handling. IF PDO can't connect we get the catch block to fire...otherwise the try block which is where our data is sent to the db... You see we have a variable called $sqlStatement.. this is made through $dbConnect->prepare(). This function takes the statement... notice variables are excluded for question marks. Inside the try block we call execute from the statement...this takes and array of values that will replace the question marks in order.

remember to create sno variable. I added date for you. also be sure all cases and spellings are right. One letter in your query string, whether spelled wrong, or even just cased wrong will cause a failure.

let me know if there's any errors or questions. jeremybenson11@gmail.com

Comment: One more tip :) I see you have some strange naming conventions. your $_POST variables, variables that hold $_POST data, and your tables are all cased different. It's pretty confusing and can make it harder to catch errors... especially case errors.